# In-line video playing in Flutter?

Tags: video, dart, flutter

I am at my wits end, by using Flutter to play in-app video. Can someone tell me how can I use videos to play in-line in a list view coming from an API in an Flutter app.

Tried many libraries but can't seem to resolve. Desperately seeking a solution. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shahz

Answer (score 1):

I believe Flutter can only play video full screen right now.

Comment: Hi @Luke Pighetti, I don't mind Flutter playing full screen but I want the video to sit in the list view (with a thumbnail) and when clicked/tapped upon should play the video, doesn't matter if it plays in full screen. I don't want it opening a separate browser/player to play the video.

Comment: I believe you'll need to have thumbnails available to show as an image that a user taps on which fires up the full screen video feature.

Comment: Thanks @Luke Pighetti, any suggestions on how to do this? assuming we have an Vimeo video url through API and we are successful in showing the thumbnail too, but how to fire up the full screen video feature on the User tap? ... any suggestion will be highly useful and appreciated. Thanks.